# mocking a method inside another method return null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have service method "customerDetails" to get more info about customer and change some field that using another method inside it "getById" when I do the unit test for customerDetails I mock the other method but the test faild because the mock return null . I try some solutions I found like checking the order of dependencies and using @InjectMocks (which I do)but they did not work for me and I do not know where the problem is.

code snippet to understand me better

**customerService**

```java
public class customerService {

    public Customer customerDetails(int id) {
        CustomerDto customer = getById(id) //here is the problem 
        // rest of the code
    }

    public CustomerDto getById(int id) {
        Optional<Customer> customer =
            this.customerRepository.findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse(id); //return null here

        if (!customer.isPresent()) {
            // code to throw Exception customer not found                
        }
        //code to retrieve customer 
    }
}
```

**customerServiceTest**

```java
public class CustomerServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void createMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    @Test
    public void testCustomerDetails() {
        CustomerDto actualResponse = DummyCutomer.createDto(); // the actualResponse is filled successfully 
    
        when(customerService.getById(actualResponse.getId()).thenReturn(actualResponse); // but here it send to getById null !! 
    
            //rest of code
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to mock the injected dependency which is the `customerRepository` in your case (not the `getById` method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the `customerRepository` not the `getById` method
For example:

```
when(customerRepository.findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse(actualResponse.getId()).thenReturn(Optional.of(WHAT_EVER_YOU_WANT));
```

In your case I think you have tow scenarios:

findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse => Optional.of(a customer instance)
findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse => Optional.empty()